# Most efficient SSIS dummy component

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I frequently want to use a dummy component as the endpoint for either an Error Redirect or Conditional Split. (See diagram) I use this so I can view the dataset while debugging.

[image: Dummy Component Flow]

I normally use Multicast as the dummy component, but was curious if it was the most efficient component to use (once the package goes into production).

I could make the component disable when not running in debug, but wanted to see if there was a component that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Multicast transformation the way you have described but only for initial debugging. It is the most easiest to deal with as a dummy component. However, I don't think you can disable the `Data Flow Sources`, `Data Flow Transformations` or `Data Flow Destinations` that exist within **Data Flow Task**. I think only the Control Flow tasks can be disabled using Expressions. You can leave the Multicast but you might want to delete the Data Viewers before you publish the package to production.

Answer (score 0):

We usually use the TRASH Destination that we downloaded from here:

http://www.konesans.com/products/trash-destination.aspx

Comment: I've used this before.  I'm just not sure I want to install it on the production server.